# Chrome <select> profiler shows long function calls

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-devtools, profiling, html-select

Initially, I thought I had a problem with my Angular application.

Then I did this simple test, opened up a fresh Chrome (v69) instance (without extensions) and loaded this simple HTML file:

```
<select name="favorites">
      <option value="American">American flamingo</option>
      <option value="Greater">Greater flamingo</option>
      <option value="Lesser">Lesser flamingo</option>
      <option selected value="Andean">Andean flamingo</option>
      <option value="Chilean">Chilean flamingo</option>
      <option value="James's">James's flamingo</option>
</select>
```

Then I ran the profiler (DevTools > Performance > Record) and used the mouse to change the options in the select a few times. Then hit stop and the result was this:

[image: DevTools profiler html select]

As you can see, for each time I select a new option (I did this 5 times), there is a "Function Call" that is running endlessly. The code was plain HTML with no Javascript.

Can anybody explain this, please?

Comment: Reported in https://crbug.com/839905.

Comment: Not present in v64, introduced in v65